# Reminder in android

Tags: android

I wanted to create a reminder  app for my android. Actually I wanted to save reminders and the dates in the database and show the reimnder when the scheduled time is reached. Can anyone please suggest the code for this. Can alarms be given specific id at the time of saving and used to retrieve the specific reminder from database. I am new to android. Please help me.

Comment: We are not here to provide you with full apps. We are here to help you with problems you face whilst programming. Also, we'd like for you to do some effort first: what have you tried already?

Comment: You really need to purchase an Android reference as suggested below. This process involves a boot receiver, the alarm manager, a subsequent notification receiver and some kind of interface for creating/viewing reminders

Comment: Wrote a tutorial. Notification Reminders: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. Your question is to broad for stackoverflow. But i would suggest you picking up a copy of [Android For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Android-Application-Development-For-Dummies.productCd-047077018X.html)

This has a full tutorial of exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have purchased the book and checked the code. Unfortunately  when I run the program , when I set mutiple reminders , only the last one is being displayed. Can you please suggest a fis for this.

Comment: You will need to post some code.. It must be a problem with either how you are storing the dates in your database, or how you are setting the alarms up.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `Notifications` in conjunction with the `AlarmManager`. There are lots of tutorials on the web that explain how to do this. Here is one: http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification